# images donot display in my wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress

i try this code to display image in my post in wordpress but image doesnot show in my post

```
<article class="media">
     <h2>About the venue</h2>
        <img class="pull-left" src="images/hotels/contempo.jpg" alt="Hotel Contempo"/>
           <p>All CAC speaking events located at 309 1st Avenue, in Downtown Seattle..</p>
  </article>
```

is this code a proper way to display images in wordpress ??...i donot want upload image method
if not correct ..how can i write code to display this image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  you want to show the static images you need to give proper `url` to the images.

```
src="/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/images/hotels/contempo.jpg"
```